# Spring boot arguments from comand line

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have SpringBootApplication that takes args

```
public class RocksdbBootApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(RocksdbBootApp.class);
        app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port", args[0]));
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

How can I get access to args in RestController?

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/rocks")
public class RocksApi {
    public RocksApi(KeyValueRepository<String, String> rocksDB) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access arguments passed to your application you can make use of [`ApplicationArguments`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationArguments.html) and inject it into your controller :

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/rocks")
public class RocksApi {

    private final ApplicationArguments arguments;

    @Autowired //can be ommited in new versions of Spring
    public RocksApi(final ApplicationArguments arguments) {
        this.arguments = arguments;
    }

    public RocksApi(KeyValueRepository<String, String> rocksDB) {
        String[] args = arguments.getSourceArgs();
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

afaik, you're setting an application property, and can acccess that like any other Spring property:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/rocks")
public class RocksApi {

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private Integer serverPort;
```